# Multiple consumers using spring kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I am looking to setup multiple listeners on a kafka topic inside my application. Below is my setup. it is supposed to be consumed by both the groups, but it is consumed by only one listener. What am i missing here?

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupName);

    return props;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(consumerConfigs());
    return consumerFactory;
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(100);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean("notificationFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> notificationFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(100);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@Bean("insertContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> insertContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConcurrency(100);

    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}

@KafkaListener(id = "insert_listener", topics = "${kafka.topic.readlocation}", group = "insert_listener", containerFactory = "insertContainerFactory")
public void receiveForInsert(String message) {
    locationProcessor.insertLocationData(message);
}

@KafkaListener(id = "notification_listener", topics = "${kafka.topic.readlocation}", group = "notification_listener",containerFactory="notificationFactory")
public void receiveForNotification(String message) {
    locationProcessor.processNotificationMessage(message);
}
```

Edit: Below is the code that worked

```
@KafkaListener(id = "insert_listener", topics = "${kafka.topic.readlocation}", groupId = "insert_listener")
public void receiveForInsert(String message) {
    locationProcessor.insertLocationData(message);
}
```

Comment: I have one consumer factory with concurrency is 2 and 5 @KafkaListener is using this consumer factory with different group id... Question: now I have 5 or 10 consumers or only one consumer reading from 5 topics? Using the latest version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a different `group.id` for each; the `group` property is not the `group.id` - see the javadocs. In the upcoming 1.3 release, there is a new `groupId` property and we also can use the `id` as a group if present.

For earlier version you need a different consumer factory for each.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks. I upgraded to 1.3 release and used the group.id.

Comment: I have one consumer factory with concurrency is 2 and 5 @KafkaListener is using this consumer factory with different group id... Question: now I have 5 or 10 consumers or only one consumer reading from 5 topics?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments on old answers; ask a new question instead. Each listener will have 2 consumers (10 total), but the topics will need at least 2 partitions each, otherwise one of the consumers will be idle.